# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. Failed to transform flipper-integration-0.73.1-debug.aar

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this error while trying to run my react native application, how do I better solve this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform flipper-integration-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.73.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download flipper-integration-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.73.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/flipper-integration/0.73.1/flipper-integration-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/flipper-integration/0.73.1/flipper-integration-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org
> Failed to transform react-android-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download react-android-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.73.1/react-android-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.73.1/react-android-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)
> Failed to transform material-1.9.0.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download material-1.9.0.aar (com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.9.0/material-1.9.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/1.9.0/material-1.9.0.aar'.
> > No such host is known (dl.google.com)
> Failed to transform constraintlayout-2.0.1.aar (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download constraintlayout-2.0.1.aar (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.0.1/constraintlayout-2.0.1.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.0.1/constraintlayout-2.0.1.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform viewpager2-1.0.0.aar (androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download viewpager2-1.0.0.aar (androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/viewpager2/viewpager2/1.0.0/viewpager2-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/viewpager2/viewpager2/1.0.0/viewpager2-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform dynamicanimation-1.0.0.aar (androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download dynamicanimation-1.0.0.aar (androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/dynamicanimation/dynamicanimation/1.0.0/dynamicanimation-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/dynamicanimation/dynamicanimation/1.0.0/dynamicanimation-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not download legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-core-utils/1.0.0/legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-core-utils/1.0.0/legacy-support-core-utils-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform hermes-android-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download hermes-android-0.73.1-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.1)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/hermes-android/0.73.1/hermes-android-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/hermes-android/0.73.1/hermes-android-0.73.1-debug.aar'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org
> Failed to transform coordinatorlayout-1.2.0.aar (androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download coordinatorlayout-1.2.0.aar (androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.2.0/coordinatorlayout-1.2.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/coordinatorlayout/coordinatorlayout/1.2.0/coordinatorlayout-1.2.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform recyclerview-1.1.0.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download recyclerview-1.1.0.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.1.0/recyclerview-1.1.0.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.1.0/recyclerview-1.1.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform recyclerview-1.1.0.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not download recyclerview-1.1.0.aar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.1.0/recyclerview-1.1.0.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.1.0/recyclerview-1.1.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform cardview-1.0.0.aar (androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download cardview-1.0.0.aar (androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform documentfile-1.0.0.aar (androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not download documentfile-1.0.0.aar (androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.0/documentfile-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/documentfile/documentfile/1.0.0/documentfile-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not download localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/localbroadcastmanager/1.0.0/localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/localbroadcastmanager/1.0.0/localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com
> Failed to transform print-1.0.0.aar (androidx.print:print:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Could not download print-1.0.0.aar (androidx.print:print:1.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/print/print/1.0.0/print-1.0.0.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/print/print/1.0.0/print-1.0.0.aar'.
> > dl.google.com

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.